# Сокращение до сотых, в переменной

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть переменная $value она выводит в фильтре значение (Цвета, названия, числа)
Есть некотоыре числа типа. 4.0999999999999996.
Как сделать, чтобы и текст выводила, и сокращало если, что такие числа до сотых.
Заранее спасибо большое.

Answer (score 2):

[round](http://www.php.su/round())

> round -- Округляет число типа float

Comment: Попробывал round($value) Место слов, выводиться ноль.

Comment: Какие слова должны выводится?

Comment: Там много каких, фильтр про на опенкарте, 
Часть из них(
Гикори (hickory) (2)
 Дуб (oak) (72)
 Дуссия (doussie) (3)
 Ироко (iroko) (2)
 Клен (maple) (5)
 Махагон (mahogany) (1)

)

Comment: Что в переменной? И текст и числа?
Как вариант можно находить числа регуляркой, округлять и вставлять обратно.

Comment: Да и текст и числа. выбираються из базы.

Comment: Вам правильно VladD сказал, при составлении строки нужно сразу форматировать число, а не после того как строка готова.

Comment: Этот модуль делал не я же)

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего, у вас в корне неверный подход. Вы не должны запаковывать данные в строку, а потом снова выковыривать их оттуда с риском ошибиться.

Нужное форматирование должно применяться в той точке, где вы собираете строку из данных.

Comment: То-есть правильный подход к данной проблеме, править сам модуль filterpro?

Comment: Каким образом можно написать данную функцию, которая будет проверять и разделять на числа и слова.

Comment: @bajex: Если вы получаете от него данные в таком формате, и ни в каком другом невозможно — данные, поставляемые этим модулем, не предназначены для для дальнейшей обработки. Узнайте у разработчиков модуля, какие он поставляет официальные API.

Comment: У меня есть файлы которые обрабатывают, вывод.

Comment: Вообщем перед выводом добавил 
                <?php   if(is_numeric($value)) {
               $value = round($value, 2);
             } 
             ?>
Всем спасибо за отклик.

Answer (score 1):

Используй

```
float round ( float $val [, int $precision = 0 [, int $mode = PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP ]] )
```

Например:

```
a = 3.643153;
b = round(a, 2);   // 3.64
```

Comment: Уже решил.